# how can I change the properties of DataGridViewImageCoulmn to be stretchImage (as pictureBox)?

Tags: c#

how can I change the properties of DataGridViewImageCoulmn  to be stretchImage (as pictureBox)?

in my DataGridView- have a DataGridViewImageCoulmn, I add it image of different sizes, it is changing the row height. I want to set a fixed height of the image and of the line

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn` have a property named `ImageLayout` that may server your need.

Comment: I found the layout - what next? (image layout=?) this is my code:  ((DataGridViewImageColumn)MyDataGridView.columns[0]).ImageLayout

Comment: = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch :-)

Comment: work well, but not nice, in my DataGridView- have a DataGridViewImageCoulmn, I add him image of different sizes, before it is changing the row height.
I want to set a fixed height of the image and of the line